# Is it necessary to have catalyst control center processes enabled for graphics options to function?

Tags: amd-catalyst

I have a very low performance computer (AMD C-50) and I just want my thirty core processes enabled at boot time. I was wondering if the MOM and CCC proceesses for the catalyst control center are required for the PowerPlay options to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering I am not sure what you mean by "PowerPlay Options", I can only give you my advice and experience. My experience is that they are both superflous, and can be disabled. If you want to do this so you can easily get them back if something goes wrong, do this:

Open a command box and type in

> msconfig

and hit enter. Go to the startup tab, and uncheck those two programs (you will probably have to reboot), then test. If you don't like the results, you can just reenable them.